# Simple RegEx Expression

Tags: c#, regex

OK I am admittedly terrible at RegEx as I rarely have a need for it, but I found myself in a situation where a simple parse just was not cutting it.  So after attempting to teach myself the entirety of RegEx while sitting here at work I finally give up and asked the experts.  I am simply parsing a sql file and splitting it on the `GO` statements.  Problem is I can't pull **GO** out of other words, like `CREATE TABLE GOPHER`.  So I think I'm pretty safe by saying I split when I have a line that's is only spaces and the word **GO** case insensitive.

Here's what I have, I think it's pretty close, but I am doing something wrong as it's not matching anything at the moment.

```
^+\s*[GO]\s*\Z
```

*note case can be taken care of with the ignore case flag, so I'm not to worried about that

If I simply write

```
^+[GO]+\Z
```

It mostly works, but it doesn't ignore the spaces before and after the `GO`, I thought `\s*` would do it, but it seems to be returning no matches.  Anybody can fix this for me, with a short explanation of what I'm flubbing up here?

Comment: `[GO]` means **'G'** or **'O'**. If you want the entire string simply write `GO` or `(GO)`

Comment: Ah I see, so my space logic was correct, I was just being stupid in thinking that was what was breaking it between the second and first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Regex.Split with the pattern `@"(?<=\bGO\b)"`, which matches the zero-width boundary immediately after the complete word "GO".

See

- [Zero-Width Positive Lookbehind Assertions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookbehind_assertion)
- [Anchors in Regular Expressions : Word Boundary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w#WordBoundary)

Comment: Is there any advantage over using this, over the other answer?  @"^+\s*(GO)\s*\Z" as this seems to be working for me and I'd have to do a little more work to completely understand your answer.

Comment: The "other answer" WOULD match "years ago" and would not match "GO;". With Regex, as with any language, you should describe what you actually mean: "Split after the separate word 'GO'". Also, SQL can be delimited by semicolons instead of newlines, so using a word boundary anchor is better than an newline anchor.

Comment: Doesn't the ^ mean new line then spaces?  So years ago is not newline then spaces, there's other letters in there?  But I guess you are right with GO;  Thanks for the help.

Comment: `@"^\s*"` does, but you have an extra plus sign in the pattern in your comment that makes the pattern nonsensical. But again, the following is valid SQL: `CREATE TABLE X(COLY INTEGER);GO;CREATE INDEX...`